# Win32 C++ - Check if the Window PositionX/PositionY and Width/Height changed

Tags: c++, winapi, window, height, width

It is possible to check whenever the X/Y position of the window changed? Also, if it's possible to check if the Window Width/Height changed too.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to set the maximum boundaries, there's already something along the lines of `WM_GETMAXMININFO` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`WM_MOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631.aspx) and [`WM_SIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx) messages.

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, you can handle `WM_SIZE` and `WM_MOVE`.  But you can also intercept the messages before they have any effect by checking [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653(v=vs.85).aspx) (except in the case where a call to `SetWindowPos` passes `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING` - but that is usually deliberate and completely under your control).  This message is useful for cleanly handling window size/position restrictions or doing window snapping.  If you force stuff to happen during `WM_SIZE` or `WM_MOVE` you will get flickering etc.