# How to know when the the size of a window has changed in Windows?

Tags: windows, size, signals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Win32 C++ - Check if the Window PositionX/PositionY and Width/Height changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713728/win32-c-check-if-the-window-positionx-positiony-and-width-height-changed)

Is there any signal in Windows which enables to know when the window size has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a message called [`WM_SIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646):

> Sent to a window after its size has changed. A window receives this
>   message through its WindowProc function.